# Persistent HTTP connection Java

Tags: java, http, tcp, httpurlconnection

I know that when using HttpURLConnection Java tries to *reuse* the same TCP connection for multiple requests to server unless there is a limitation from server side. Indeed, when I see wireshark log, one of the `requestHeaders` of HTTP header is Connection: keep-alive.  But when server returns data I see a TCP  `[FIN,ACK]` packet being sent back to server from my side.

How exactly does this *reuse* the tcp connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTTP 1.0 there are no official specifications regarding the idea of persistent connections. For a persistent connection to work the client **requests** the connection to be kept opening by the addition of the `Connection` header as such:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

If the server decides that the connection should be kept-alive (i.e. not closed) it to should respond with the header:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

followed by keeping the connection alive for whatever defined period of time it chooses. Please note that the keep alive "feature" is not a official protocol feature of HTTP 1.0 and thus servers are not required to facilitate the client's request should the client request it.

In HTTP 1.1 it became implicit of persistent connections so if you see this happening on a server responding with HTTP/1.1 headers suspect that the server isn't adhering to HTTP 1.1 standards (unless the server explicitly responds with a `Connection` header with the value of `Close`).

In any case however there is a timeout period as defined by the server in which subsequent requests should be sent in by or else the connection is dropped. This is to prevent a spam of unclosed connections should clients drop without properly closing the connection.

The Java `HttpURLConnection` object attempts to *reuse* the TCP connection but upon failure will simply fall back to creating a new TCP connection.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked my log again, and the server does seem to respond with HTTP/1.1 OK response, however the Connection header has value of: Close. I suppose the server is configured that way.

Comment: @astralmaster Keeping the connection open does facilitate more efficient content transmission but also leaves servers vulnerable to DoS attacks as multiple persistent connections can be opened (wasting server resources) which can quickly overwhelm the server. Disabling persistent connections can almost be seen as a safety measure in this case (though not exactly a very effective one).